# How to permanently show sign/encrypt buttons in Evolution when composing a mail

Tags: encryption, toolbar, evolution

If one is composing a mail in Evolution and wants to sign/encrypt it, one needs to go via *Options › PGP sign*  and *Options › PGP Encrypt*  (4 clicks). That done, the corresponding buttons show up in the toolbar.

Now, would they be there in the first place, the action would just require 2 clicks (one on each button). I've looked throughout all settings I could find in the GUI, but didn't see a corresponding option. Is it possible to have these two buttons always visible – if not through the GUI, maybe via `gconf`/`dconf` settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the PGP Sign / Encrypt buttons in the compose window for Gnome Evolution is easy; it's in the dconf settings:

```
apt install dconf-editor
```

In dconf editor, search for `composer-toolbar-show-sign-encrypt` and enable it.

The full path in dconf is:

`/org/gnome/evolution/mail/composer-toolbar-show-sign-encrypt`

Comment: "enabling … is easy": yes, full ack. The difficulty just lies in finding the place. Ticking the box indeed was easy, LOL :D – Thanks!

Comment: PS: Note this only seems to affect accounts having an "OpenPGP key id" configured (i.e. pressing new/reply/… while in one of those accounts). If you started from another one, even switching the "From" field to a PGP enabled account won't show the encrypt buttons. Just in case someone wonders.

Answer (score 1):

The `dconf` command for the command line to permanently show the encryption button in the compose window toolbar of Evolution is

```bash
dconf write /org/gnome/evolution/mail/composer-toolbar-show-sign-encrypt true
```

You might need to install `dconf-cli`.